# How to fuzzy search for a specific person into a list of people (concatenated surname+lastname)

Tags: c#, .net, fuzzy-search

I am trying to match an input (coming from a third-party software) like this:

`PIPPO CANASTA PER  FT 501 del 1/11/2016`

against a list of people that can be modelized as an array of strings (coming from another software)

```
[
  ...
  "CANASTA              PIPPO"
  ...
]
```

How can I accomplish this using C# (.NET)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a fuzzy search. If you'd accept "Cannasta" it would be. You can search for "Levenshtein distance" if you're interested in that.

Comment: [.NET library for text algorithms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508307/net-library-for-text-algorithms)

Comment: Stefan Szakal's Blog [Text similarity algorithms via C#](http://www.stefanszakal.co.uk/text-similarity-algorithms-via-c/) looks interesting too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each string into an array of words and search the list for the most number of matching elements:

```
string[] arrayToSearch = new string[] {
    "OTHER STUFF",
    "CANASTA              PIPPO",
    "MORE STUFF"
};

string stringToFind = "PIPPO CANASTA PER  FT 501 del 1/11/2016";

string[] wordsToFind = stringToFind.Split(default(Char[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string bestMatch = arrayToSearch.OrderByDescending(
    s => s.Split(default(Char[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Intersect(wordsToFind, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
          .Count()
).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Best match: " + bestMatch);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The suggestion is nice and simple, I must admit. 
I am going to add some kind of logic (such as words 'weight') because I have some weird cases when prepositions and/or abbreviations can return misleading results

Comment: One simple way to improve the above search results would be through taking into account matching words length, but depending on the size of the list being searched and how often it updates you might as well consider some ready-made solutions.

Comment: thank you for adding the snippet. That's more less what I ended up with.

Comment: I could evaluate some libraries but I have no idea from where to start. googling didn't lead me to desired results

Comment: I use SQL Server [Full-text Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) in my work, and it yields pretty good results, I have also seen some pure .net implementations of the above with few layers of cleaning and filtering that works rather well too.